# JQuery to see if image alt tag is in variable array and then add class

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have an html grid of images.  I want to use JQuery to add HTML to all images that have an alt tag that match items from a list, or array.

There are varies posts about using JQuery to add a class to html if a specific alt tags are found, but I'm trying to do this with a list of alt tags. I can make it work if I only have one value in the variable.  How do I make it work with a whole list of values for alt tags?

```
<main class="grid">
<div><img src="/images/image_1.jpg" alt="1904380_ORAN"></div>
<div><img src="/images/image_2.jpg" alt="1904380_VANI"></div>
<div><img src="/images/image_3.jpg" alt="1904380_WHIT"></div>
<div><img src="/images/image_4.jpg" alt="1904381_BERR"></div>
</main>

$(document).ready(function() {

var list = ("1904381_BERR", "1904380_ORAN");                        
$('img').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("alt") == list ){             
          $(this).before("<img src=/images/guide/dropped.png class=cxl>");
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: `var list = ("1904381_BERR", "1904380_ORAN");` isn't an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment need to use an array and just check that *alt* contains required value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var list = ["1904381_BERR", "1904380_ORAN"];

    $('img').each(function() {
        if (list.indexOf($(this).attr("alt")) !== -1) {
            $(this).before('<img src="/images/guide/dropped.png" class="cxl">');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would recommend adding the quotes around the "src" and "class" attribute.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Is there a way to have the array values come from a separate file?

Comment: Yes, you can define the array in the separate **js**-file and embed it using [script-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). As an alternative, you can prepare these values on server-side and inject them to html-markup and then parse on client-side using [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/). When this data is dynamic then make sense to request it by ajax from server-side.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4b0k7qc/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var list = ["1904381_BERR", "1904380_ORAN"];
  $('img').each(function(_i, _e) {
    if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('alt'), list) > -1) {
      $(this).before('<img src="/images/guide/dropped.png" class="cxl">');
    }
  });
});
```

There was some problems with your code.

- The list variable was not an array
- The way you compared the list to an array was incorrect.
- The `<img>` tag you include `before` needs more quotes to separate the attributes.